# MFMailComposeViewController - change cancel and send button to images

Tags: iphone, ios, button, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to customize the MFMailComposeViewController such that it has my custom images/buttons instead of the default "cancel" and "send" buttons. I tried googling for an answer but couldn't find anything
that could help me.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can't change MFMailComposeViewController. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Important:** The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.